# Revert dropdown to default option after Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown with a couple of fields that are used for updating an entry in the db. However I have an issue when I click submit to have a dropdown go back to initial - default state.

Here is the dropdown

```
<select className="select--field" name="products" onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e)}}>
    <option value={null}>Please select a product</option>
    {data.products.map(({id, productName}) => (
         <option key={id} value={id}>{productName}</option>
     ))}
</select>
```

*What handleChange does is setting up selected product id as currently selected product so I can map through data and set placeholders as pre-filled data in fields below (not shown here).*

I get the data via GraphQL useQuery, it might be that I am not controlling this field as I should so I can't really control it after an event like onSubmit. All suggestions are welcome, thnx.

Comment: When you submit the form to your server, does it reload?

Comment: Yes, you should control it. `value={this.state.product}` or something like that. Then simply reset the state's value to `null`.

Comment: @Chris no it doesn't reload, I'm using mutation to update, it would perhaps allow me to call a clear values function inside onCompleted option in the mutation but I've put it in the onClick in submit button

Comment: @ChrisG oddly enough that didn't work, I've put the initial state to null and passed it to the first option outside of the map, I believe the issue there is the value being controlled in the map by the id of the loop while outside I'm using state. But useRef worked so fine, thanks for the input though.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `null` apparently, but `""` works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-allen-on5s2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). It is an effective tool to control your form elements.

Here is an example (https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-haze-zmq4t?file=/src/App.js):

```
const products = [
  {id: 112, productName: "Prod 1"},
  {id: 113, productName: "Prod 2"},
]

export default function App() {
  const dropdown = useRef();

const handleChange = () => {
  console.log('do stuff...')
  setTimeout(() => {dropdown.current.value = ""}, 2000) // <- simulating some process...
  
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <select ref={dropdown} className="select--field" name="products" onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e)}}>
        <option value={""}>Please select a product</option>
        {products.map(({id, productName}) => (
            <option key={id} value={id}>{productName}</option>
        ))}
    </select> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using a ref is fine in general, but here it is a workaround, not the proper solution for this.